# Place fragments inside a linear layout on the top of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have split the screen in two parts using a LinearLayout, one contains a fragment and the other contains 2 fragments inside a scroller.
I'm using android studio and in the preview mode the screen shows that the fragments of both sites are placed on the top, that's what i want. However, when I try it with a device, these fragments are placed in the middle of the screen. But I want to have the two columns on the top.
I tried to use layout_gravitity and gravitity on the LinearLayout container but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:gravity="top">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="org.gvsig.roads.mobile.fragments.itineraries.NewItineraryTabReferenceFrag_"
    android:id="@+id/frag_reference_new_itinerary"
    tools:layout="@layout/new_itinerary_tab_reference_frag"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top" />


<ScrollView
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/between_contents_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="org.gvsig.roads.mobile.fragments.itineraries.NewItineraryTabTimesFrag_"
            android:id="@+id/frag_time_new_itinerary"
            tools:layout="@layout/new_itinerary_tab_times_frag" />
        <fragment
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/between_contents_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="org.gvsig.roads.mobile.fragments.itineraries.NewItineraryTabNotesFrag_"
                android:id="@+id/frag_notes_new_itinerary"
                android:layout_below="@+id/frag_time_new_itinerary"

                tools:layout="@layout/new_itinerary_tab_notes_frag"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use relative layout instead of linear and set fragment to top using alignparenttop = true.

Comment: I need to have two clumns that's why I use LinearLayout, if I change it to relative layout, one of the columns dissapear

Comment: you can set relative layout orientation as horizontal and try once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note the widths = **0dp**. This is needed for weights to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top"
    >
    <!-- This will  be 100% high, 50 wide -->
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name="org.gvsig.roads.mobile.fragments.itineraries.NewItineraryTabReferenceFrag_"
        android:id="@+id/frag_reference_new_itinerary"
        tools:layout="@layout/new_itinerary_tab_reference_frag"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
    />
    <!-- This will be 100% high, 50 wide -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/between_contents_margin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:name="org.gvsig.roads.mobile.fragments.itineraries.NewItineraryTabTimesFrag_"
                android:id="@+id/frag_time_new_itinerary"
                tools:layout="@layout/new_itinerary_tab_times_frag"
            />
            <fragment
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/between_contents_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:name="org.gvsig.roads.mobile.fragments.itineraries.NewItineraryTabNotesFrag_"
                android:id="@+id/frag_notes_new_itinerary"
                android:layout_below="@+id/frag_time_new_itinerary"
                tools:layout="@layout/new_itinerary_tab_notes_frag"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But I want that the other framgent frag_reference_new_itinerary stays at the top too

Comment: It merges the fragments into only one column, I have to keep two separated columns, but with its elements aligned on the top

Comment: I edited my answer, in order to have 2 columns, equally wide. The second one having 2 cells.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_reference_new_itinerary"
    android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginepiechart.NewItineraryTabReferenceFrag_"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_time_new_itinerary"
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginepiechart.NewItineraryTabTimesFrag_"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_notes_new_itinerary"
            android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginepiechart.NewItineraryTabNotesFrag_"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frag_time_new_itinerary" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I need to have two columns, using relative layout make dissapear one

Comment: plz post your screenshot